# Can I grab the inserted IDs when doing multiple inserts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In my head this sounds improbable, but I'd like to know if I can do it:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
VALUES ('First'),
('Second'),
('Third'),
('Fourth'),
('Fifth');

SELECT INSERTED Name, ID FROM TheAboveQuery
```

Where ID is an auto-indexed column?

Just to clarify, I want to select ONLY the newly inserted rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with SQL Server 2008 you can use OUTPUT clause with INSERT statement

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.Name INTO @T
VALUES 
   ('First'),
   ('Second'),
   ('Third'),
   ('Fourth'),
   ('Fifth');

SELECT Name, ID FROM @T;
```

UPDATE: if table have no triggers

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.Name
VALUES 
   ('First'),
   ('Second'),
   ('Third'),
   ('Fourth'),
   ('Fifth');
```

Comment: Is this better to use than the other answer, from a performance standpoint?

Comment: if you have no triggers on MyTable you can use faster statement without table variable see update

Comment: I went with your statement, I use the selected rows to update other rows so it fit my needs better.

Comment: Good job @DmitryKolchev 

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use an [`IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) property on your `ID` field, and create the `CLUSTERED INDEX` on it

[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://rextester.com/KLKBE31733)

```
create table MyTable (  ID int identity(1,1), 
                        [Name] varchar(64),
                        constraint [PK_MyTable] primary key clustered (ID asc) on [Primary]
                     )


--suppose this data already existed...
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
VALUES 
('First'),
('Second'),
('Third'),
('Fourth'),
('Fifth');


--now we insert some more... and then only return these rows
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
VALUES 
('Sixth'),
('Seventh')


select top (@@ROWCOUNT)
    ID, 
    Name 
from MyTable
order by ID desc
```

[`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns the number of rows affected by the **last** statement executed. You can always see this in the messages tab of SQL Server Management Studio. Thus, we are getting the number of rows inserted and combining it with [`TOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which limits the rows returned in a query to the specified number of rows (or percentage if you use [PERCENT]). **It is important that you use `ORDER BY` when using `TOP` otherwise your [results aren't guaranteed to be the same](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)**

From my previous edited answer...

*If you are trying to see what values were inserted, then I assume you are inserting them a different way and this is usually handled with an OUTPUT clause, TRIGGER if you are trying to do something with these records after the insert, etc... more information would be needed.*

Comment: I only want to retrieve that values that were inserted.

Comment: How are you inserting them?

Comment: As above, `INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
VALUES ('First'),
('Second'),
('Third'),
('Fourth'),
('Fifth');`

Comment: That's awesome! Can you point me to anything to help me understand why this works?

Comment: I've added some documentation to the post. Click on those links and read throughly

Comment: this is not solution in concurrent multiuser environment like SQL Server. other users at the same time can insert records in MyTable. highly likely in concurrent multiuser environment you select records inserted from other sessions

Comment: @DmitryKolchev in my previously entered I touched on an output clause but the OP stated they were simply inserting the data using insert into w/ hard coded values. Thus, this solution is fine. No one would use an application with concurrent sessions to insert data this way. The DV is comical if it was you

Comment: in a single-user scenario your decision is acceptable (I'm sorry, I did not understand this), but if it is not so then this is the way to run into the problem. Perhaps it makes sense to say about the limitations of this solution